# Powershell ISE popup window on top

Tags: powershell

I have 3 kind of windows in my code i need to force them to show up on top, how can i do that?

Here is the code for popup window 1:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog -Property @{SelectedPath = 'c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\’}

[void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
$outputfolderpath = $FolderBrowser.SelectedPath

$outputfolder = "$outputfolderpath$slash"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
```

I tried `$FolderBrowser.Topmost = $true` But i get error saying:

Property 'Topmost' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.

Popup window 2:

```
$messagebox = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Some Messge" , "Status" , 4)
```

For this one `$messagebox.Topmost = $true` gave me the same error.

How can i make them to popup on top?

Answer (score 1):

When I create a new Internet Explorer window using `$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application` I'm able to tap into User32.dll and set that window to TopMost using it's handle.

If you're able to get the form or windows handle, this code might be useful.

```
$signature = @"

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);  

public static IntPtr FindWindow(string windowName){
    return FindWindow(null,windowName);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd,
IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);

const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;

const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;

public static void MakeTopMost (IntPtr fHandle)
{
    SetWindowPos(fHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
}

public static void MakeNormal (IntPtr fHandle)
{
    SetWindowPos(fHandle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
}
"@
```

Then I use the ComObject's handle to make it TopMost then Normal.

```
$hWnd = $ie.HWND
$app = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name Win32Window -Namespace ScriptFanatic.WinAPI -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms -Using System.Windows.Forms -PassThru
$null = $app::MakeTopMost($hWnd)
$null = $app::MakeNormal($hWnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those classes support a `TopMost`-property, but both show the dialog / popup as the topmost window of the application (PowerShell ISE). The `MessageBox` does also steal focus from another active application.

`[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show()` doesn't return a messagebox-object, it returns the result as a `DialogResult`-object, so you can't modify it using your `$messagebox`-property.

Comment: I wouldn't ask for help if those popups would show on top, you say they does, but they doesn't when i run them in my code.

Comment: I understand, but I can't reproduce your problem using your sample code... They both take focus.. Have you tried a different computer?

Comment: No as I only need to run it on my VPS, the only window that is covering the popup is the powershell itself, is there a command that would minimalize powershell window before any popup appear?